# dart flutter max value from list of objects

Tags: flutter, dart

Looking for some help how to select oldest age from users in flutter object list...

```
users = [
  { id: 123, name: 'Bob', age: 25},
  { id: 345, name: 'Joe', age: 44},
  ...
];
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First make sure your list has the correct type and format:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> users = [
  {"id": 123, "name": "Bob", "age": 25},
  {"id": 345, "name": "Joe", "age": 44},
  {"id": 35, "name": "Joxe", "age": 40},
];
```

Then you can do this:

```
if (users != null && users.isNotEmpty) {
  users.sort((a, b) => a['age'].compareTo(b['age']));
  print(users.last['age']);
}
```

Another way would be:

```
if (users != null && users.isNotEmpty) {
  dynamic max = users.first;
  users.forEach((e) {
    if (e['age'] > max['age']) max = e;
  });
  print(max['age']);
}
```

---

Another one:

```
if (users != null && users.isNotEmpty) {
  print(users.fold<int>(0, (max, e) => e['age'] > max ? e['age'] : max));
}
```

And this one requires `import 'dart:math'`:

```
if (users != null && users.isNotEmpty) {
  print(users.map<int>((e) => e['age']).reduce(max));
}
```

Comment: Be cautious with the first solution, the sorting modifies the list!

Answer (score 13):

I'd use the list `reduce` function, docs [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/reduce.html).

```
var oldestUser = users.reduce((currentUser, nextUser) => currentUser['age'] > nextUser['age'] ? currentUser : nextUser)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void main() {
  var users = [
    {"id": 123, "name": 'Bob', "age": 25},
    {"id": 345, "name": 'Joe', "age": 44},
    {"id": 35, "name": 'Joxe', "age": 40},
  ];
  users.sort(ageCompare);
  print(users.first);
}

int ageCompare(u1, u2) => u2['age'] - u1['age'];
```

try it on https://dartpad.dartlang.org

---

or just one-liner

```
  users.sort((Map u1, Map u2) => u2['age'] - u1['age']);
  print(users.first);
```